# Multiple linear regression isn't giving any output

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm using `LinearRegression()` function of `sklearn.linear_model`and it is getting stuck.
Here's my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

reg=LinearRegression()
reg.fit([[0],[1],[2]],[0,1,2])
print(reg.coef_)
reg1=LinearRegression()
reg1.fit([[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]],[0,1,2])
print(reg1.coef_)
```

The output is:

```
[1.]
```

Then it gets stuck without any error or exception. Even tried with real data. I'm using `python 3.6.5` on `ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: Can you explain what get stuck means? Because this works fine for me

Comment: Same setup as yours. The code works fine.

Comment: Well the python interpreter keeps on running without crashing or showing any errors